# How to customize text in permission dialog in Xamarin.forms for Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions

I make a Xamarin.Forms App and making permissions for location,camera etc. I made custom text permission dialog in IOS for location like this:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Test Message.</string>
```

but i can't find how to make it in Android. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is not custom error message on Android. The OS handles the messages itself.

Comment: You mean message dialogs like :"The App want to access your location" can't be customized?

Comment: Correct. The way to go there is to display a pop-up before the OS message appears and in your pop-up you'll explain why the app wants to request the specified permission. After the pop-up call the logic to request the permission.

Comment: I've added an answer with a reference to the official docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, you **can't**.

As per Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#request-permission):

> Note: Your app cannot customize the dialog that appears when you call launch(). To provide more information or context to the user, change your app's UI so that it's easier for users to understand why a feature in your app needs a particular permission. For example, you might change the text in the button that enables the feature.

What you can do, and they advise the developers to do, is to adjust your UI or display a pop-up describing why you'll require the specified permission.